# A dialog box gets two values and performs all arithmetic operations on it then show it in JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that receives 2 numbers from user using a dialog box and then performs all arithmetic operations on it then show it at once. I tried writing it but its not compiling it ,

```
package javaapplication4;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



  @author Muhammad Tariq

public class JavaApplication4 {
    private static Object joptionpane;
    static int add(int x,int y){
        return x+y;
    }
    static int sub(int x,int y){
        return x-y;
    }
     static int div(int x,int y){
        return xy;
    }
      static int mul(int x,int y){
        return xy;
    }


      @param args the command line arguments

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String a,b;
        a = JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog(Enter 1st number);
         b = JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog(Enter 2nd number);

         int ad=add(Integer.parseInt(a),Integer.parseInt(b));
         int sb=sub(Integer.parseInt(a),Integer.parseInt(b));
         int dv=div(Integer.parseInt(a),Integer.parseInt(b));
         int ml=mul(Integer.parseInt(a),Integer.parseInt(b));

         JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ad.tostring()+n+sb.tostring()+dv.tostring()+ml.tostring()+);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of errors in the code ,such as wrong method name toString(), missed operations between numbers (div and mult methods), uncommented javadoc (@author and @param), missed double quotes around the Strings (Enter 1st number..etc), calling methods on primitive types (toString() on int) and no such variables (n). So, on the next time read the compiler error messages to understand where is the wrong. This is the code what you want:

```
package javaapplication4;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


/**
  *@author Muhammad Tariq
**/
public class JavaApplication4 {
    private static Object joptionpane;
    static int add(int x,int y){
        return x+y;
    }
    static int sub(int x,int y){
        return x-y;
    }
     static int div(int x,int y){
        return x/y;
    }
      static int mul(int x,int y){
        return x*y;
    }

/**
*     @param args the command line arguments
*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String a,b;
        a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1st number");
         b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 2nd number");

         int ad=add(Integer.parseInt(a),Integer.parseInt(b));
         int sb=sub(Integer.parseInt(a),Integer.parseInt(b));
         int dv=div(Integer.parseInt(a),Integer.parseInt(b));
         int ml=mul(Integer.parseInt(a),Integer.parseInt(b));

         JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ad+"  "+sb+" "+dv+" "+ml);
    }
}
```